# /admin/v1/users giving a 40103 in DUO Security Admin API

Tags: java, duosecurity

I am trying to create using  /admin/v1/users it shows

```
{
 "code":40103,
 "message":"Invalid signature in request credentials",
 "stat":"FAIL"
  }
```

Here is my Java Code:

```
   public class DuoCreateUsers {

    private static SortedMap<String, Object> params = new TreeMap<String, Object>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String ikey = "x";
        String skey = "x";
        String host = "api-d221a358.duosecurity.com";
        String httpMethod = "POST";
        String requestPath = "/admin/v1/users";
        String timestamp = OffsetDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME);

        String username = "newuser";
        String email = "abc@example.com";

        params.put("username",username);
        params.put("email",email);

        String queryString = canonQueryString();

        String canonicalRequest = timestamp + "\n" + httpMethod + "\n" + requestPath +  "\n" + queryString;
        System.out.println("canonicalRequest = " + canonicalRequest);

        String signature = sign1(canonicalRequest, skey);
      //  System.out.println("signature = " + signature);

        String url = "https://" + host + requestPath+"?"+queryString;
        System.out.println("url = " + url);

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setHeader("Date", timestamp);
        httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((ikey + ":" + signature).getBytes()));
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(params.toString()));
        // Make the request
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String responseContent = entity != null ? EntityUtils.toString(entity) : "";

        String rs =  "Response Status Code: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + "\nResponse Content:\n" + responseContent;
        System.out.println("rs = " + rs);

    }


    public static String canonQueryString()
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        ArrayList<String> args = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String key : params.keySet()) {
            String name = URLEncoder
                    .encode(key, "UTF-8")
                    .replace("+", "%20")
                    .replace("*", "%2A")
                    .replace("%7E", "~");
            String value = URLEncoder
                    .encode(params.get(key).toString(), "UTF-8")
                    .replace("+", "%20")
                    .replace("*", "%2A")
                    .replace("%7E", "~");
            args.add(name + "=" + value);
        }

        return com.duosecurity.client.Util.join(args.toArray(), "&");
    }

    private static String sign1(String data, String secretKey) {
        try {

            // Create an HMAC-SHA1 key from the secret key
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "HmacSHA1");

            // Initialize the HMAC-SHA1 algorithm
            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
            mac.init(secretKeySpec);

            // Calculate the HMAC-SHA1 hash
            byte[] hmacSha1Bytes = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            // Convert the result to a hexadecimal string
            String hmacSha1Hex = bytesToHex(hmacSha1Bytes);

            // Print the HMAC-SHA1 hash
            System.out.println("HMAC-SHA1: " + hmacSha1Hex);

            return hmacSha1Hex;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    // Helper method to convert bytes to a hexadecimal string
    private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder hexStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            hexStringBuilder.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }
        return hexStringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

What is the wrong of my code?

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

The below code was working for me

Generate signature of the request code

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class GenerateHMACSignature {

    public String generateTheToken(String canonicalString, String ikey, String skey)  {
        return getAPISignature(canonicalString,ikey,skey);
    }


    public String getAPISignature(String url,String ikey,String skey)  {

        Mac sha1Hmac = null;
        try {
            sha1Hmac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(skey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "HmacSHA1");
            sha1Hmac.init(secretKey);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
           // log.error("error in");
            return StringUtils.EMPTY;
        }
        byte[] signatureBytes = sha1Hmac.doFinal(url.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String  signature= Hex.encodeHexString(signatureBytes);
        String auth = ikey + ":" + signature;
        System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
}
```

For creation of user code

```
import com.ciscoduo.bulkgenerator.model.CiscoDuoCreateUserResponse;
import com.ciscoduo.bulkgenerator.utilies.GenerateHMACSignature;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


@Service
public class CreateUser {

    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");

    private String currentTime = dateFormat.format(new Date());

    @Autowired
    private GenerateHMACSignature generateSignature;


    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    public CiscoDuoCreateUserResponse createUser(String username) throws Exception {
        String ikey = "DIEZT523RM4GZ4ETBJBQ";
        String skey = "3z9e75OxFp7TuxzHJDWtctntsp2hu0UlkRgr9VxQ";

        String url = String.format("https://api-43c07036.duosecurity.com/admin/v1/users?username=%s", username);
        URL apiUrl=new URL(url);
        String canonicalString = String.join("\n",currentTime,"POST",apiUrl.getHost(),apiUrl.getPath(),apiUrl.getQuery());
        System.out.println(canonicalString);
        String token = generateSignature.generateTheToken(canonicalString, ikey,skey);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        headers.set("Authorization", "Basic " + token);
        headers.set(HttpHeaders.DATE, currentTime);
        HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<CiscoDuoCreateUserResponse> ciscoDuoResponse = restTemplate.
                exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, CiscoDuoCreateUserResponse.class);
        return ciscoDuoResponse.getBody();
    }


}
```

The pojo class is

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class CiscoDuoCreateUserResponse {

    private String stat;
    private ResponseData response;

    @Data
    public static class ResponseData {
        private long created;
        private String email;
        private String firstname;
        private String status;
        @JsonProperty("user_id")
        private String userId;
        private String username;
    }
}
```

The main class is

```
import com.ciscoduo.bulkgenerator.service.CreateUser;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import java.net.URL;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BulkgeneratorApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private CreateUser createUser;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BulkgeneratorApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                    }
                    public void checkClientTrusted(
                            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                    public void checkServerTrusted(
                            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                }
        };

        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    createUser.createUser("john");

    }
}
```